# Sqlite directory database path error with Flutter and Linux?

Tags: linux, flutter, sqlite, dart

**Hi**,help me i have an error please

```
/data/user/0/com.example.qr_reader/app_flutter/ScansDB.db
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62sZV.png)

Comment: It looks to me like you don't have an error. You have information printed to the console. If you are pretty sure that it is an error, a little more information would be helpful. (like what you are trying to do, the block of code you think is giving the error, etc.)

Comment: Hi, I can't find the database path because it gives me the following. 

path:data/user/0/com.example.qr_reader/app_flutter/ScansDB.db

Comment: what happens if you open a terminal and do `cd /data/user/0/com.example.qr_reader/app_flutter/ && ls`?

Comment: sqlite gives me the mentioned path, but it doesn't exist